# Oracle: Very slow to purge table from recycle bin

Tags: oracle

I ran a "PURGE TABLE" command on a table in the Recycle bin. It has now been running for 25 minutes and still going on. Is it normal for a purge to take that long?
Is it safe to cancel (I'm using SQL developer which has a cancel button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My database server was out of disk space, which caused the never-ending purging.